# I cannot build drawable resource file

Tags: android, android-drawable

Suppose If I create a drawable resource file name `background_rect_shape` and call it from layout i.e. `android:background="@drawable/background_rect_shape"`, Then after when i build my application it shows this error :

```
Error:(14, 29) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'background' with value '@drawable/background_rect_shape).
```

Comment: check this file in drawable folder   background_rect_shape and upload screen shot also

Comment: Try to clean your project.

Comment: Yes there is a file name inside a drawable folder.

Comment: can u attached screen shot

Comment: Try cleaning the project.

Comment: Thank you all. Well cleaning does the trick :) So silly of me..

Comment: @user2273146 Yes, happens to me a lot !! :)

Answer (score 1):

This error means that R.java does not have a reference to the image file in question.
Check R.java under gen folder and find out if it has a location reference to the image file you added.  If it does not, these are the possible reasons.

1. You have added an image file to a wrong drawable folder. There are three drawable directories, namely
   drawable-hdpi, drawable-ldpi, drawable-mdpi. Try to add image to all three directories and one of them will work depending on the resolution size of your image.
2. You have another file in the folder with the same name. Rename one of them so that there are no name conflicts.

If it still not works -

**1. Try cleaning the project and rebuild again.**